# Getting array out of something in php

Tags: php, laravel

I don't even know what should I call this type of data but I need to get array out of it.

## Code

```
$folderss = $ssh->exec($command);
$folders = explode(',', $folderss);
```

## DD result

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => """
    DO_NOT_UPLOAD_HERE\n
    domains\n
    public_html\n
    """
]
```

## What I need

```
array:3 [▼
      0 => "DO_NOT_UPLOAD_HERE",
      1 =>  "domains",
      2 => "public_html",
]
```

**any idea?**

## Update

I changed my code to:

```
$folders = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $folderss);
```

Now I'm getting:

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => "DO_NOT_UPLOAD_HERE"
  1 => "domains"
  2 => "public_html"
  3 => ""
]
```

**I have 1 extra row there, how to remove it?**

## Update 2

If I use

```
$folders = explode("\n", $folderss);
```

same result as using `preg_split` happens (extra line)

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => "DO_NOT_UPLOAD_HERE"
  1 => "domains"
  2 => "public_html"
  3 => ""
]
```

Comment: You changed the question so that it is now asking something entirely different. This makes answers invalid.

Comment: @ryantxr what did i change?! I still want to make array out of my dd data

Comment: @ryantxr I need to get array out of it by `preg_split` or `explode` or anything else i didn't change anything, still want the same thing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to remove empty values from array

```
 $folders = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $folderss); 
 $folders=array_filter($folders);
```

Comment: thanks, i used your filter and it removed my empty line however I'm using explode now (second update)

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

`$folders = explode(',', $folderss);`

by:

`$folders = explode('\n', trim($folderss, '"');`

Comment: same results, still getting `array:1 [▼
  0 => """
    DO_NOT_UPLOAD_HERE\n
    domains\n
    public_html\n
    """
]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_filter` to remove the empty values from an `array`

```
$folders = array_filter(preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $folderss));
```